# Quickly calculating particle proximity in a 3 Dimensional Space

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, loops

This may seem like a simple question, yet I see no other route i can take at this time. Without too many unnecessary details, the general concept is as follows:

I have many instances of an entity (think particles) within a contained 3-Dimensional space. The number of initial instances may vary from 10's to 1000's of said particles, each initialized with it's identifying number, and it's own x, y, and z coordinate. The particles may move overtime, and so the goal here is to be able to, as quickly as possible, check to see if any two particles are within a pre-set proximity distance of each other (in any direction). The simplest, and yet unfortunately inelegant/slow method I can think of is embedded for loops as follows:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < upper; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < upper; j++)
        {
            //If within proximity
            if(sqrt( ((entity1.x[i] - entity2.x[j])*(entity1.x[i] - entity2.x[j])) + ((entity1.y[i] - entity2.y[j])*(entity1.y[i] - entity2.y[j])) + ((entity1.z[i] - entity2.z[j])*(entity1.z[i] - entity2.z[j])) ) <= proximity )
            {
                //Perform function
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my actual loop in my code. I am utilizing the distance formula in 3 Dimensions, seeing if said distance is less than the pre-defined proximity. If they are within that distance, then I perform a function. Currently I have the function to literally do nothing, so I can watch the timing for just the loop itself, and not worry about the algorithm inside. I know times vary per system, but my system is at least upper average, if not better and this loop thats around 5 seconds to complete, and this is with upper set to 100 loops. Is there a faster algorithm to do this? Or am I doing something horribly inefficient in this loop? The quicker I can make this, the better.

Thank for the help,
DevenJ

Comment: well you don't have to perform the expensive sqrt() calculation...

Comment: Why is that? Can you explain why I wouldn't need the sqrt()? Is there a distance formula that does not call for it?

Comment: This is called [Nearest Neighbour search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_search). There are many techniques for doing this more quickly such as using [spatial hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing) ([here](http://conkerjo.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/spatial-hashing-implementation-for-fast-2d-collisions/) is a good article) or spatial partitioning with [kd-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or [octrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).  Which one is best depends on the number and distribution of your points.

Comment: Thank you David! I knew there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to touch on here is that you should not be using square root to do your calculation if speed matters. A better way would be to square the proximity value and remove the square root.

You will also want to to make sure you don't repeat calculations. For example, think about the approach below

```
for(int i = 0; i < upper; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < upper; j++)
    {
        if(i < j)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

But binary octrees are a better solution though they require a greater algorithmic knowledge.

Comment: Thank for the info! I'll have to look up binary octrees, those are new to me. However, I'm not sure where the "if(i < j)" comes into play?

Comment: @DevenJ If you already checked whether element `i` is close to element `j`, you don't also have to check if element `j` is close to element `i`. The if statement helps you avoid doing that.

Comment: But i and j in this case, just serve as instances of two different types of particles (entity1, and entity2). So entity1.x[1] != entity2.x[1], or atleast not necessarily. The index is just the number for the instance of that given entity.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the need to use sqrt() inside the loop by setting

```
proximity = proximity * proximity;
```

before the loop.

Comment: Completely right. I can't believe I oversaw that... However, I'm still not seeing a great speed increase. Is there a different algorithm aside from embedded for-loops, to check and see if there are particles near one another? Basically a way to do it within a single for loop? Or am I stuck with this performance?

Comment: I don't think there's a "quick fix" that will give you better performance than this, but it looks like you're getting a few good comments (that you'll need to research) about how to improve it using more advanced techniques.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Not necessarily looking for anything quick. This is for my own personal purposes, so I can spare the time to do this right. Thanks for all the helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

Storing your entities in a data structure that partitions your space will allow you to eliminate any particles that aren't contained in the partition which contains your proximity area. Binary space partitionings, quadtrees and octrees are useful for this.

Comment: I'll have to look into them, as right now I don't see how partitioning the space would save calculations... Unless I can somehow tell which particles are within the space subdivisions... I'll look into quadtrees and octrees and see what they tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For positive values, if `a <= b`, then `a^2 <= b^2`.

The square root operation preserves the ordering between the two values.  So just square your proximity before the loop to match the squared magnitudes.